# Is there a free linux distribution that provides network services with an Web interface?

Tags: linux, vpn, ipsec, gateway, dhcp-server

What I have in mind and used is a commercial gateway/firewall with an web-interface for configuration that has this specifications:

```
Administration
Network
Monitoring and logging
Authentication
Firewall
IPS and iDS
VPN server
Multiple internet gateways
Bandwidth management
Public dns
Application firewall
SSL-VPN webportal
High availability
Content scanning: web traffic
Content scanning: mail traffic
Statistics
```

But the software comes only at cost embedded on their devices.

What I found as a free alternative on internet is [ZeroShell](http://www.zeroshell.net/eng/) but is still beta and might not have some features needed. 
Is there an established distribution of linux or other free *nix that can provide the network services needed in a company and provide also a web interface for some of the configuration, logs etc much like the above mentioned aXsGUARD?

One mandatory feature, needed in most of the companies, is Multiple Internet Gateways. If there is not available this kind of distribution with Web interface, what would be the next best free solution in the sense of having both an interface and the shell just for advanced users.

Comment: The right way to go about this is to determine what your actual requirements are, and then find a product that meets those requirements. A "one size fits all" solution will probably either be too expensive, or not do everything you actually need.

Comment: @MichaelHampton What I am more interested is Multiple Internet Gateways, VPN, Proxy, DHCP, all with an web interface and free.

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu: Shopping and product recommendation questions are off-topic on all [SE] sites. Please read the [FAQ] for more details.

Comment: @SvenW I guess is a question of *cui bono*, since a distribution is more than a product, a distribution might have more than a product around them, also there is AskUbuntu which in itself is around a product, since my post is more centered on the specific requirements than product recommendation I hope is somehow acceptable. I edited the post to eliminate any mentions to a product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pfSense](http://pfsense.org) does everything you need it to with a very nice web interface to boot.  It's based on FreeBSD with images for multiple platforms.  I currently run an ALIX 2D2 kit from [here](http://netgate.com), granted I only have one WAN interface but the [ALIX](http://pcengines.ch/alix.htm) platform provides multiple form factors to suit most needs.  I don't work for any of these companies, I've just found their products and services to be very good.

Comment: Does it provide web-interface also for Multiple Internet Gateways features?

Comment: Yes, multiple WAN and LAN interfaces are supported.

Comment: Yes, I just looked in the feature list: *Highly flexible policy routing possible by selecting gateway on a per-rule basis (for load balancing, failover, multiple WAN, etc.*